# Error when trying to execute drag and drop using javascript for Selenium WebDriver test

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

I have tried to simulate drag and drop for Selenium WebDriver test using the following JavaScript call, but I get a WebDriver error. I tried this way, as with **Actions** class didn't work on any browser (Firefox, Chrome).
Can someone tell what I am doing wrong?

```
String filePath = "C://Work//Spica import files//drag_and_drop_helper.js";
String source = "li[draggable='true']";
String target = "#fieldCc";
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
String line;
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
  br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

try {
  while((line = br.readLine())!=null)
    buffer.append(line);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

String javaScript = buffer.toString();
javaScript = javaScript + "$('" + source + "').simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: '" + target + "'});";
((JavascriptExecutor)getDriver()).executeScript(javaScript);
```

The error that I get is:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error:
>   Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: missing ) after
>   argument list   (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.116)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The
>   server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or
>   timeout: 17 milliseconds Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision:
>   'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30
>   19:26:09' System info: host: 'EN610188', ip: '172.16.116.151',
>   os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_91' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities
>   [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false,
>   chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\lgrecu\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir5352_12600},
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>   version=53.0.2785.116, platform=WIN8_1,
>   browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true,
>   acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   fe314c5e2184e76f1b3d934159ae2887 Build info: version: '2.53.1',
>   revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time:
>   '2016-06-30 19:26:09' System info: host: 'EN610188', ip:
>   '172.16.116.151', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64',
>   os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_91' Driver info:
>   driver.version: unknown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the single quotes from `String source = "li[draggable='true']";` and try now. guess it will work.

```
String source = "li[draggable=true]";
```

Comment: welcome:) if my solution worked then make a vote for it.

Comment: Do you have any idea how could I convert this xpath: **.//*[contains(@class,'removable secure')]//span[@title='value']/ancestor::li**, into a css locator ? I have to use dynamic xpaths for simulating drag and drop action, so **value** will be replaced with multiple strings

Comment: Instead of passing the element locators into executeScript method you can use something like this,

`WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("someXpath"));
WebElement ele2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("someXpath"));

javaScript = javaScript + "arguments[0].simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: arguments[1] });";
((JavascriptExecutor)getDriver()).executeScript(javaScript,ele1,ele2); `

Comment: I tried that approach, but I get this error: `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: arguments[0].simulateDragDrop is not a function
  (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)`

Comment: Eventually, it worked with: `javaScript = javaScript + "$(arguments[0]).simulateDragDrop({ dropTarget: arguments[1]});";`

Comment: Thanks for the hint anyway, it was helpful! I just had to add an extra character :)