# Unable to perform drag and drop action even code executed without any error

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Unable to see element dragged in AnjularJS application even though drag and drop actions performed without any error.

Below is the code:

```
WebElement draggable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='page-content-wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li/ul/li[2]/span/span[1]"));
WebElement droppable = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='page-content-wrapper']/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div[1]"));
```

Below are different methods performed and executed without error:

```
1)
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(draggable).click(droppable). keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();

2)Method 2
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
            builder.clickAndHold(draggable).moveToElement(droppable).build();
            builder.dragAndDrop(draggable, droppable).perform();

3)Method 3
Actions action = new Actions(driver); 
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            action.clickAndHold(draggable2).build().perform();
            action.moveToElement(droppable2).build().perform();
            action.release(droppable2).build().perform();

4)
Method 4
Actions actions = new Actions(driver); 
        browser.actions()
        .mouseDown(draggable2)
        .mouseMove(draggable2)
        .mouseUp(droppable2)
        .perform();
```

Also performed JavaScript methods :But no luck it also executes without error but unable to perform drag and drop action in UI[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awKKU.jpg)

```
    A) public static void DragAndDropJS2(WebElement source, WebElement destination, WebDriver driver) throws Exception 
    {
       // JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        String xto=Integer.toString(source.getLocation().x);
        String yto=Integer.toString(destination.getLocation().y);
        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("function simulate(f,c,d,e){var b,a=null;for(b in eventMatchers)if(eventMatchers[b].test(c)){a=b;break}if(!a)return!1;document.createEvent?(b=document.createEvent(a),a==\"HTMLEvents\"?b.initEvent(c,!0,!0):b.initMouseEvent(c,!0,!0,document.defaultView,0,d,e,d,e,!1,!1,!1,!1,0,null),f.dispatchEvent(b)):(a=document.createEventObject(),a.detail=0,a.screenX=d,a.screenY=e,a.clientX=d,a.clientY=e,a.ctrlKey=!1,a.altKey=!1,a.shiftKey=!1,a.metaKey=!1,a.button=1,f.fireEvent(\"on\"+c,a));return!0} var eventMatchers={HTMLEvents:/^(?:load|unload|abort|error|select|change|submit|reset|focus|blur|resize|scroll)$/,MouseEvents:/^(?:click|dblclick|mouse(?:down|up|over|move|out))$/}; " +
                "simulate(arguments[0],\"mousedown\",0,0); simulate(arguments[0],\"mousemove\",arguments[1],arguments[2]); simulate(arguments[0],\"mouseup\",arguments[1],arguments[2]); ",
                source,xto,yto);

    }



    B) public static void DragAndDropJS(WebElement source, WebElement destination, WebDriver driver) throws Exception 
    {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("function createEvent(typeOfEvent) {\n" +"var event =document.createEvent(\"CustomEvent\");\n" +"event.initCustomEvent(typeOfEvent,true, true, null);\n" +"event.dataTransfer = {\n" +"data: {},\n" +"setData: function (key, value) {\n" +"this.data[key] = value;\n" +"},\n" +"getData: function (key) {\n" +"return this.data[key];\n" +"}\n" +"};\n" +"return event;\n" +"}\n" +"\n" +"function dispatchEvent(element, event,transferData) {\n" +"if (transferData !== undefined) {\n" +"event.dataTransfer = transferData;\n" +"}\n" +"if (element.dispatchEvent) {\n" + "element.dispatchEvent(event);\n" +"} else if (element.fireEvent) {\n" +"element.fireEvent(\"on\" + event.type, event);\n" +"}\n" +"}\n" +"\n" +"function simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(element, destination) {\n" +"var dragStartEvent =createEvent('dragstart');\n" +"dispatchEvent(element, dragStartEvent);\n" +"var dropEvent = createEvent('drop');\n" +"dispatchEvent(destination, dropEvent,dragStartEvent.dataTransfer);\n" +"var dragEndEvent = createEvent('dragend');\n" +"dispatchEvent(element, dragEndEvent,dropEvent.dataTransfer);\n" +"}\n" +"\n" +"var source = arguments[0];\n" +"var destination = arguments[1];\n" +"simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(source,destination);",source, destination);
        Thread.sleep(1500);

    }



    c) public static void DragAndDropJS1(WebElement source, WebElement destination, WebDriver driver) throws Exception 
    {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("function createEvent(typeOfEvent) {\n" +"var event =document.createEvent(\"CustomEvent\");\n" +"event.initCustomEvent(typeOfEvent,true, true, null);\n" +"event.dataTransfer = {\n" +"data: {},\n" +"setData: function (key, value) {\n" +"this.data[key] = value;\n" +"},\n" +"getData: function (key) {\n" +"return this.data[key];\n" +"}\n" +"};\n" +"return event;\n" +"}\n" +"\n" +"function dispatchEvent(element, event,transferData) {\n" +"if (transferData !== undefined) {\n" +"event.dataTransfer = transferData;\n" +"}\n" +"if (element.dispatchEvent) {\n" + "element.dispatchEvent(event);\n" +"} else if (element.fireEvent) {\n" +"element.fireEvent(\"on\" + event.type, event);\n" +"}\n" +"}\n" +"\n" +"function simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(element, destination) {\n" +"var dragStartEvent =createEvent('dragstart');\n" +"dispatchEvent(element, dragStartEvent);\n"  +"var dropEvent = createEvent('drop');\n" +"dispatchEvent(destination, dropEvent,dragStartEvent.dataTransfer);\n" +"}\n" +"\n" +"var source = arguments[0];\n" +"var destination = arguments[1];\n" +"simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(source,destination);",source, destination);
        Thread.sleep(1500);   
    }
```

All the above mentioned methods and commands are compilled and executed without any error but unable to perform drag and drop operation in UI (PLEASE HELP).

Tried with all the possible combinations that I know can any one let me know am I missing some thing?
FYI am using Chrome 53 and Firefox 42 will that make any differnece?
Is there any other tool which satisfies my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the elements present in the webpage are not HTML5 web elements. Because selenium doesn't have support for performing actions on HTML5 elements.

Have look at http://elementalselenium.com/tips/39-drag-and-drop to know how to perform drag and drop operation on HTML5 elements using javascript.

This thread may also help you - [Error when trying to execute drag and drop using javascript for Selenium WebDriver test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39720614/error-when-trying-to-execute-drag-and-drop-using-javascript-for-selenium-webdriv/39721243?noredirect=1#comment66749828_39721243)

Comment: Hi Sudharsan, It seems to be HTML5 web element only as none of the selenium and Java Scripts with Jquery methods are not impacted on elements.Thanks for the reply and info                                                                If Not Selenium is there any other tool that works for Angular JS application (specifically drag and drop actions)?
Can anyone please let me know any tool that works for my requirement.

Comment: Issue has been resolved by using SIKULI tool (i.e, using image based identification) am able to perform Drag and Drop operation.

Comment: Screen screen=new Screen();
  Pattern ClickDrag=new Pattern("C:\\Users\\sridharp\\Desktop\\Sridhar\\ExpStudio\\ClickDrag.JPG");
  Pattern ClickDrop1=new Pattern("C:\\Users\\sridharp\\Desktop\\Sridhar\\ExpStudio\\ClickDrop1.JPG");                                                                                                                                  screen.dragDrop(ClickDrag, ClickDrop1);

Comment: Thnx for the help :)

Comment: using sikuli is also a good option, though!! But the only problem is that the browser window should always be in focus and I have no idea if sikuli will work with headless automation. Just make sure your browser will be always in focus during the execution